# Visual Basic Resizing Rich Text Boxes

Tags: vb.net, text, widget

I am trying to figure out how to make these widgets, in my case two Rich Text box widgets stay anchored in place so that I can resize the form that they are in and not lose its spacing. Here are some screen caps to better show what I am talking about. 
[image]

Above is what my Form looks like in visual studio before I run it. It is also how I want my form to look. The space in between the two rich text boxes is I want to retain.

[image]

Above is what happens when I run this program. My question is how can I set say "anchor points" or something like that to keep the widgets in place so that when I resize the form it will retain the spacing. In other words when I run the program it will look the same has it does in the first image.

FULL CODE: (I am not sure if having this will help but here is what I have)

```
Public Class Form1
    'Decloration 
    Private widthOffset As Integer = 30
    Private heightOffset As Integer = 30

    Private preWidth As Integer
    Private preHeight As Integer
    Private postWidth As Integer
    Private postHeight As Integer


    Private Sub RichTextBox1_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.Resize
        RichTextBox1.Width = Me.Width - widthOffset
        RichTextBox1.Height = Me.Height - heightOffset

        RichTextBox2.Width = Me.Width - widthOffset
        RichTextBox2.Height = Me.Height - heightOffset

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
        RichTextBox1.Width = Me.Width - widthOffset
        RichTextBox1.Height = Me.Height - heightOffset

        RichTextBox2.Width = Me.Width - widthOffset
        RichTextBox2.Height = Me.Height - heightOffset

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WinForms you can add the controls to a [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx), setting the [ColumnStyles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.columnstyles.aspx) for each control to either an Absolute or Percent size, so that they either stay the same size or resize as the container is resized.

More info: [Walkthrough: Arranging Controls on Windows Forms Using a TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4yc3e8c%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> The FlowLayoutPanel control and the TableLayoutPanel control provide
>   intuitive ways to arrange controls on your form. Both provide an
>   automatic, configurable ability to control the relative positions of
>   child controls contained within them, and both give you dynamic layout
>   features at run time, so they can resize and reposition child controls
>   as the dimensions of the parent form change. Layout panels can be
>   nested within layout panels, to enable the realization of
>   sophisticated user interfaces.